# How can I export / import all email aliases for an Exchange 2010 User Account?

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-2010, export, import

I have a number of users in our 2010 Exchange server. I wish to export (into a file) all the email addresses for a particular user. Later on, I wish to be able to import all the email addresses once more into the user (lets assume all the emails to be imported do NOT exist in any user account).

Anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Powershell magic, anyone?

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why you might want to do this?

Comment: A user wishes to see all their email addys. next, they wish to bulk import missing ones. They can easily do this in excel, hence the export.

Comment: Argh, I have a script that does something similar.... somewhere! I just can't find it at the minute. If I remember, I'll have a look through the SVN repo at work tomorrow to see if I can find it. I assume there's lots of aliases, so manually doing it is a no go?

Comment: Correct. the first person i looked at had around 60 odd. Also sucks how I can't figure out how a user can add an alias via their OWA or Outlook -- currently they have to send admin (my team) and email request to add one.

Comment: Any luck finding that script?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find it anywhere. I must have deleted it with our Exchange 2010 migration testing VMs.

Comment: FWIW, this link has some Powershell clues... http://forums.msexchange.org/m_1800435933/mpage_1/key_/tm.htm#1800435933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

In exchange powershell ...

```
> $mbx = Get-Mailbox someUserName
> $mbx.EmailAddresses | where { $_.IsPrimaryAddress -eq "False" } | Export-CSV "C:\SomePath\wherever.csv"
> $mbx.EmailAddresses | where { $_.IsPrimaryAddress -eq "False" } | foreach { $mbx.EmailAddress -= $_.SmtpAddress }
> Set-Mailbox someUserName -EmailAddresses $mbx.EmailAddresses

> $mbx = Get-Mailbox theNewUser
> Import-CSV "C:\SomePath\wherever.csv" | foreach { $mbx.EmailAddresses += $._SmtpAddress }
> Set-Mailbox theNewUser -EmailAddresses $mbx.EmailAddresses
```

that's it :)

Of course, you might need to modify the contents of the csv file after the export and before the import.

I also had to delete all the existing email's from the `someUserName` so there were no duplicates in `theNewUser`

good luck :)